# How to select from a list at specific locations

Tags: filtering

Suppose that a list can be generated for a sum of primes as follows:

```
g[n_]:= g[n]= Sum[Prime[j], {j, n}];
lst = Table[g[n], {n, 1, 1000}];
```

Now that a list has been created what is an efficient way to select values at Lucas number positions ? The result should read `{2, 10, 17, 58, ...}`. I have tried several version of Select,

```
Select[Range[10], Extract[ LucasL[#]][ lst[[#]] ] &]
Select[Range[10], Pick[ lst[[#]], LucasL[#] ] &]
```

and all lead to empty results.

For context: The calculation process above was/is an attempt to speed up the sum

```
f[n_]:= f[n]= Sum[Prime[i], {i, LucasL[n]}];
Table[f[n], {n,1,50}]
```

Any ideas on how to select data from particular positions or how to speed up the calculation of the series would be most helpful.

Comment: `lst[[Table[LucasL[n], {n, 1, 10}]]]`?

Comment: try also `lst[[LucasL@Range@10]]` or `Extract[lst, LucasL[List /@ Range[10]]]` or `Extract[lst, List /@ LucasL[Range@10]]`?

Comment: you can also map `g` on `LucasL[Range@10]` (that is,  `g /@ LucasL[Range@10]`), instead of generating a larger table and filtering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

g1[n_] := g1[n] = Sum[Prime[j], {j, n}];

t1 = AbsoluteTiming[
   lst1 = Table[g1[n], {n, 1, 1000}];][[1]]

(* 0.142708 *)
```

The definition of `g1` repeatedly calculates identical values of `Prime`. Using a recursive definition avoids this.

```
g2[1] = Prime[1];
g2[n_] := g2[n] = g2[n - 1] + Prime[n];

t2 = AbsoluteTiming[
   lst2 = Table[g2[n], {n, 1, 1000}];][[1]]

(* 0.002815 *)
```

The second method is about 50 times faster

```
t1/t2

(* 50.6956 *)
```

The different definitions give identical results.

```
lst1 === lst2

(* True *)
```

To find the maximum value of `n`

```
nmax = Floor@NMaxValue[{n, LucasL[n] <= 1000}, n]

(* 14 *)
```

Then, as pointed out in the comments

```
lst1[[LucasL@Range@nmax]]

(* {2, 10, 17, 58, 160, 501, 1480, 4438, 13101, 38238, 110364, 
    316421, 901478, 2549658} *)
```